# How to enable wp-admin and wp-login only over highport

Tags: multisite, security

For security reasons we want to make our Wordpress login over wp-admin and wp-login only available over highport.

We have a multisite-installation (with two websites).

On the internet I didn't found any existing solution for this. There must be a way to achieve this.

Can somebody please help?

Comment: You should be able to do this with web server configuration. Which web server are you using? Remember that you’ll still need to allow access to wp-admin/admin-ajax.php

Comment: I use apache2.x

Comment: OK, then you should be able to solve this with `<Location>` and `Deny from all` in the normal port numbers' VirtualHost blocks. I've had a quick search for duplicates but none look quite right to me.

Comment: thank you alot, you were a great help!